# What are some common uses of various blending modes?

Tags: photo-editing, layers

Photo editors have a number of blending modes: Normal, Lighten, Darken, Colour Burn, Multiply, and so forth.

I know the [formula](http://www.flyingmeat.com/acorn/docs/blending%20modes.html) each of them applies to blend the layers, and that's fine for understanding exactly what each of these modes does, but I'm at a loss as to how to actually use them. What are some common uses of each of these modes? How can I use them to perform common tasks in photo editing?

I'm using Acorn 3.5.1, in case it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off: Even [Andrew Kramer](http://www.videocopilot.net/), king of After Effects, simply goes through all blending modes to find an appealing effect. So playing with them is a really good option.
There *are* common uses for some blending modes, though:

**Screen** and **Add** both make dark parts of the image transparent. (That is, the color from the layers below will show through dark parts.)
This is often used for explosions on a dark background, since you only want the bright parts of the explosion to show.
The difference between those two is that *Add* really adds brightness. If the bottom layers have a fairly bright spot and the layer on top (with the *Add* blending mode) is fairly bright in the same place, the result will get even brighter and might clip. With screen, you will simply see the brightest one - either the top layer or those below.

**Multiply** is the complement to *Screen*. Bright parts will become transparent. You can often use *Multiply* on a vignette layer (although I encourage you to experiment!). **Substract** is not used nearly as often as *Add*, but should have the opposite effect.

**Overlay** acts similiar to *Screen* and *Multiply* but makes grey (50% brightness) transparent. Images of cracks for compositing purposes often come on a grey background, since you need the highlights *and* shadows simultaneously for a convincing effect. Apparently, **Hard** and **Soft Light** also eliminate grey, but have a stronger/weaker effect - just try them!

I also use the **Difference** mode to align layers. If, for example, I have two images that were shot on a tripod but do not align perfectly, I put the top one into *Difference* and nudge them around until I get an image that is as dark as possible.

Those are the blending modes you will use most commonly. But, as mentioned above, it is a good habit to play around by simply scrolling through them. Most of them are pretty specific and I do not really understand them, but sometimes *Vivid Light* just simply works best, or I choose *Hard light* rather than *Overlay* for a more 'dramatic' effect.